# How to render <object object> in template in JSON

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to angular. I have difficulties showing JSON data on my HTML.  is shown instead. How can I show the data instead of  showing ?

### cards.component.ts

```
serverData: JSON;

getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/details')
    .subscribe(data => {this.serverData = data as JSON;
      console.log(this.serverData);
    })
  }
```

### cards.component.html

```
<div>
  {{getData() | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you use ngx-datatable to visualize your data: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are returning a `Subscription` in `getData()` not `serverData`. try it like this:
**cards.component.ts**

```js
serverData:JSON;

ngOnInit(){
    // Dont forget to call getData()
    this.getData()
}

getData() {
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/details')
    .subscribe(data => {this.serverData = data as JSON;
      console.log(this.serverData);
    })
}
```

**cards.component.html**

```html
<div>
  {{serverData | json}}
</div>
```

If you need to return the data you get from the observable directly, you can use Rxjs `map()` operator.

Comment: `getData()` doesn't return an `observable`, it returns a `Subscription`. Notice that in the function, he is subscribing to the observable...

Comment: It now return nothing instead when I swap them

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I didn't mean that you have to swap anything. In your post you returned the subscription but didn't do anything with it and I thought that maybe you meant to send `data` elsewhere to be processed. If this in fact is what you want to do, you can process it right here with `map()` and subscribe to it somewhere else (or even here). [See getHeroNo404() in this angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#heroservice-inmemorydataservice-appmodule)

Comment: @Chin Added complete code. Hope it's more clear now.